# Probability of a contingency table with given marginals

Tags: contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, combinatorics

In Fisher's exact test we consider all contingency tables $(n_{ij})_{i,j=0,1}$ consistent with given marginals $(n_{0.},n_{1.},n_{.0},n_{.1})$, where $\sum_i n_{i.}=\sum_j n_{.j}=N$.
Each table has probability 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\frac{ \binom{n_{0.}}{n_{00}} \binom{n_{1.}}{n_{11}} }{\binom{N}{n_{.1}}}
\end{align}
given the marginals and the null hypothesis of independence.

How can we generalize those probabilities to $k$-way contingency tables of the kind 2x2x2x... with given $(k-1)$-dimensional fixed margins?

In order to generalize the result, I'm trying to find a counting interpretation of (1). That probability is equal to 
$$
\frac{ \binom{N}{n_{00} n_{01} n_{10} n_{11}} }{ \binom{N}{n_{1.}} \binom{N}{n_{.1}}},
$$
so is equal to the number of cases consistent with $(n_{ij})$ divided by $\binom{N}{n_{1.}} \binom{N}{n_{.1}}$. So, how can we interpret the distinct counted cases?